# ECMAScript: What does `status` mean in Syntax-Directed Operations?

Tags: javascript

In https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-algorithm-conventions-syntax-directed-operations, There is a description like this

> Syntax-directed operations are invoked with a parse node and, optionally, other parameters by using the conventions on steps 1, 3, and 4 in the following algorithm:
>
> 1. Let status be SyntaxDirectedOperation of SomeNonTerminal.
> 2. Let someParseNode be the parse of some source text.
> 3. Perform SyntaxDirectedOperation of someParseNode.
> 4. Perform SyntaxDirectedOperation of someParseNode with argument "value".

1. What does *status* in this algorithm mean? It's not used in the algorithm anymore.
2. What does the algorithm mean? It seems weird.

Answer (score 4):

That's just an **example**, it's not a real algorithm, and it's not necessarily a complete example (hence not using *status* after the first step). For a real algorithm, look at the section containing actual Syntax-Directed Operations, such as [function name inference](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/syntax-directed-operations.html#sec-static-semantics-hasname):

> **8.4.1 Static Semantics: HasName**
>
> ...
>
> 1. Let *expr* be the *ParenthesizedExpression* that is covered by *CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList*.
> 2. If IsFunctionDefinition of *expr* is **false**, return **false**.
> 3. Return HasName of *expr*.

The *status* in the example is like *expr* in the above, a temporary variable (if you will) for the algorithm. It's just that the example doesn't use *status* again (it probably should, it would be a better example).

Answer (score 3):

> What does *status* in this algorithm mean?

It's just a variable introduced by that step, like in any other "*Let `x` be …*".

> What does the algorithm mean? It seems weird.

It means nothing. It's an example algorithm in the "algorithm conventions" section explaining how algorithm steps are meant to be understood in the rest of the spec.